# run jQuery on variable and not on document

Tags: jquery, variables

Do you know if it's possible to run jQuery on a variable that contains html and not just on the document itself.

Example:

```
bg.inspectorGetRawHtml = function(){
    var c = jQuery("#bg-admin-inspect-wrapper").html();
    jQuery(".bg-admin-inspect-state", c).remove();
    console.debug(c);
}
```

So bascially, reading a segment of the pages html into a variable and then performing jQuery manipulation on that string.

If I console.debug the actual jQuery remove, it seems like does the matching, but the var is not manipulated.  I know jQuery relies on the DOM, and maybe that's why it's not working, but if anyone has any insight on this....
**Edit**
After lonesomeday's suggestion, here is the code I ended up with:

```
bg.inspectorGetRawHtml = function(){
    var c = jQuery("#bg-admin-inspect-wrapper").clone();
    jQuery(".bg-admin-inspect-state", c).remove(); //The ,c specifies what element to work on.
    console.debug(c.html());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you need is $().detach:

```
bg.inspectorGetRawHtml = function(){
    var c = jQuery("#bg-admin-inspect-wrapper").detach();
    console.debug(c);
}
```

This will remove the selected element from the DOM and allow you to perform jQuery operations on it.

---

**Edit** You can also create a piece of HTML from a string and turn it into a jQuery selection and work with it.  For instance

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newText = '<div><p>Some text here</p><img src="image.png" /></div',
        $newDiv = $(newText);

    $newDiv.addClass('someClass');

    $('body').html($newDiv);
});
```

This creates a new div with a paragraph of content and an image, adds the class "someClass" to the div and replaces the content of the page with the new div.

Comment: oh yeah, duh.  Thanks lonesomeday.  I actually used clone() as I wanted to leave the original data on the page.